# How do I call python program (which has command line arguments) from PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, python

My Python Program is,

```
from xbee import ZigBee
import serial
import sys

sPort = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(sPort)

targStr = sys.argv[1]
data = str(targStr)
print (data)
destAdd = "\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xa9\xcc\xad"
xbee.send("tx",dest_addr_long=destAdd,dest_addr="\xff\fe",data=data)
print ("Sent!")
```

When I execute this python program on linux shell, it works all great! How do execute this program on certain event from HTML Page (Either using Javascript, AJAX or PHP) ?

Comment: Well, you can't do it directly from JavaScript (except in an environment like Node.js); and to call it with arguments from PHP, read the applicable "exec" documentation. PHP has a terrible API here, but using [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) should get the job done. (The "command" to PHP's `exec` includes the parameters.)

Comment: tried exec, but still the page remains blank. and no effect on hardware side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed this code into some Python web server - for example [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

See example bellow - xbee_test.py (it is very raw, don't use that in production environment):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from xbee import ZigBee
import serial

sPort = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(sPort)

@app.route("/<data>")
def index(data):
    destAdd = "\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xa9\xcc\xad"
    xbee.send("tx",dest_addr_long=destAdd,dest_addr="\xff\fe",data=data)
    return "Sent!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now, when you run this in Python and hit http //localhost:5000/test_data you get your code executed.

Embedding this into HTML page as e.g. AJAX call is from this point on uncomplicated.

Here is how to obtain Flask installation and run that:

```
$ pip install Flask
$ python xbee_test.py
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/
```

Comment: How do I run this ? Can you explain in a little detail ?

Comment: I add flask installation procedure + how to exec this.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still, I'm getting no response on page, neither any change in hardware side.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: No! it's just blank page.

Comment: You should see lines like:
"127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2014 05:43:25] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -"
"127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2014 05:43:39] "GET /bar HTTP/1.1" 200 -" - do you see that message "Running on http …"? after you launch Flask?